# Carrossel inclinado (diagonal) em jQuery e CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css3

Preciso fazer um carrossel inclinado (em diagonal conforme imagem) porém com transição entre os movimentos.

[image]

Eu cheguei a prototipar alguma coisa [neste JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8fcbabq/) mas o movimento só está funcionando no botão "voltar", ainda assim com uma transição abrubta no eixo Y. Quando clico no botão "próximo", ele passa ao item seguinte porém em linha reta.

Comment: Para fazer o efeito "diagonal" você pode usar o atributo CSS3 `skew()`. [**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kazzkiq/ursesba6/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você não precisar dar suporte nativo ao Internet Explorer 8, você pode usar a propriedade Transform do CSS:

```
.carousel{
    transform: rotate(-5deg)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c7wkoyfc/

Comment: IE 6,7 e 8 tem suporte com o filtro `matrix` apesar das coordenadas serem um pesadelo para calcular, existe uma [calculadora online](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html) muito útil!

Comment: Valeu, Gustavo e @Zuul! Eu usei o rotate mesmo. Porém duas vezes... Uma para inclinar a `<ul>` e outra para "desinclinar" a `<img>` de dentro da `<li>`. Só para acrescentar, eu utilizei o `backface-visibility: hidden;` para amenizar a pixelização causada pela inclinação do elementos nos browsers.

Comment: `transform: rotate(-5deg) skew(-5deg);` daria exatamente o efeito da figura. Mas o código de rolamento da pergunta tem um bug.

Comment: jsfiddle atualizado: http://jsfiddle.net/dzcosf1h/